# Dirichlet's test for convergence of improper integrals

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Dirichlet's test claims that for two *continuous* functions $f,g\in[a,\infty]$ where $f,g\geq 0$, if a certain $M$ exists such that $\left|\int_a^bf(x)dx\right|\leq M$ for every $a\leq b$, and $g(x)$ is monotonically decreasing, and $\lim_{X\to\infty}g(x)=0$, then $\int_a^\infty fg$ is convergent.

Does this also apply for a non-continuous $f(x)$? $g(x)$ is still continuous.

This question [relates to another question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/141038/24314), regarding a specific integral problem. If this is true, then my other problem will be solved.

Comment: Your version of Dirichlet's test seem to be wrong: take $f\equiv 1$ and $g(x) = 1/x$.

Comment: @Ory: Your condition should read there exists $M$ such that $\int_a^x f(t) dt \leq M$ for all $x > a$

Comment: @Ory: Also the restriction that $f$ is continuous might be a bit too strong. I think it should still work if $f$ is continuous except on a measure zero set. Hence, it will work for the problem you have posed in the other thread.

Comment: @Marvis I've stated that such $M$ should exists by stating that $f(x)$ is *upper-bounded*. Will fix the question text, thanks.

Comment: Check this reference http://books.google.it/books?id=UkQ8ANdjJUcC&pg=PA441&lpg=PA441&dq=dirichlet+test+improper+integrals&source=bl&ots=IC4VQmn272&sig=zyhp9cfkSB6_bMW1vDz85WUtldQ&hl=it&sa=X&ei=AvykT7WgFfHP4QSLr-jACQ&ved=0CGsQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=dirichlet%20test%20improper%20integrals&f=false

Comment: @Dirk I found what's missing. It's $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ that needs to be bounded, not the original $f(x)$ (just like Marvis said). Your example where $f\equiv1$ makes $\int_a^\infty 1=\infty$.

Comment: Anyway, I've still haven't found the answer I was looking for (just fixes for my typos) - Is this test also true for a non-continuous $f(x)$?

Comment: @Marvis regarding the problem on my other question - This doesn't help solve the problem with the second integral, since there're an infinite number of non-continuous points at $[a,\infty]$ for $(-1)^{\lfloor x \rfloor}$. Either that or that I didn't understand what you've explained. I haven't studied measure theory yet.

Comment: @OryBand The set of points at which the function $(-1)^{\lfloor x \rfloor}$ is $\{1,2,\ldots\}$ which is a measure zero set.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I paste here a theorem from Mathematical Analysis by S. C. Malik,Savita Aror (see also Google Books [here](http://books.google.it/books?id=L25yJhCll78C&pg=PA902&lpg=PA902&dq=abel-dirichlet%20test%20for%20improper%20integrals&source=bl&ots=&sig=Auj_knxYzbVVjanEnZgpuh1n4V8&hl=it&sa=X&ei=6_-kT_vTBe_Y4QTthZCbCQ&ved=0CF4Q6AEwAzhG#v=onepage&q=abel-dirichlet%20test%20for%20improper%20integrals&f=false))

**Theorem.** If $\phi$ is bounded and monotonic in $[a,+\infty)$ and tends to zero at $+\infty$, and $\int_a^X f$ is bounded for $X \geq a$, then $\int_a^\infty f \phi$ is convergent.

As you can see, no continuity is really necessary. Honestly, the continuity assumption appears often for the sake of simplicity. Improper integrals can be defined as limits of Riemann integrals: all you need is **local integrability**. However, we know that continuity is "almost necessary" to integrate in the sense of Riemann, so teachers do not worry too much about the minimal assumptions under which the theory can be taught.