# Improper integral - checking convergence of $\int_{1}^{\infty} x^2 \sin(x^4) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Does the following improper integral converges ? 
$$\int_{1}^{\infty} x^2 \sin(x^4) dx$$

Tried to find some known improper integral to compare this one to, but didn't find one.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. By the change of variable $x=t^{1/4}$, one gets

> $$
> \int_{1}^{\infty} x^2 \sin(x^4) dx=\frac14\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin t}{t^{1/4}} dt
> $$

The latter integral is convergent by applying the [Dirichlet test of convergence for improper integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141048/dirichlets-test-for-convergence-of-improper-integrals).

Alternatively, one may integrate by parts, for $M\geq1$:

> $$
> \int_{1}^M\frac{\sin t}{t^{1/4}} dt=\left. \frac{-\cos t}{t^{1/4}}\right]_1^M+\frac14\int_{1}^M\frac{\cos t}{t^{5/4}} dt
> $$

As  $M \to \infty$, the first term on the right hand side is finite and the latter integral is clearly absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 0):

It *does* converge. You can try [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%5Bx%5E2%20Sin%5Bx%5E4%5D,%7Bx,1,Infinity%7D%5D) to get this answer:

$$\int_1^\infty x^2 sin(x^4) dx\approx 0.150932$$