# Proving that a function is integrable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

Given that $f:[0, \infty] \to \mathbb{R}$ is decreasing with $\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)=0$, prove that

$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\cos(\frac{1}{x})f(\frac{1}{x})}{x^2}dx$$ 
converges.

I've thought about using Dirichlet test but it works only if $f$ is continuously differentiable. It can be an improper integral or not, depends how $f$ is defined, so some of my other ideas didn't work either. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use Dirichlet's test as it is formulated here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test#Improper_integrals, which doesn't require $f$ to be uniformly continuous.

Comment: Substitute $u=1/x$ and the integral becomes $\int_1^{\infty} \cos(u)f(u)du$ and the theorem cited in this solution should cover it: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141048/dirichlets-test-for-convergence-of-improper-integrals

Comment: @LanceSackless Are you sure that $f \in C^1$?

Answer (score 1):

By [Lebesgue differentiation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem), a decreasing function is almost everywhere differentiable, so for any $\varepsilon >0$
$$ \int_{\varepsilon}^{1}\frac{f(1/x)\cos(1/x)}{x^2}\,dx = \int_{1}^{1/\varepsilon}\cos(x)\,f(x)\,dx$$
and we may apply integration by parts/[Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test). It does not really matter that $f'(x)$ is not defined at some points, and we do not need the continuity of $f'$.