# Does this converge: $\int_{3}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x \cdot \ln x\ \mathrm dx}{x^2\sqrt{x^2-4}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can I use Dirichlet's test?

I know that$\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}\sin x\le 1$.

Also,  $\displaystyle\frac{\ln x}{x^2\sqrt{x^2-4}}$ is monotonic.

Also, $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\ln x}{x^2\sqrt{x^2-4}} =0$

Can then conclude that the series converges?

Comment: Short answer: yes, you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can apply the [Dirichlet test](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141048/dirichlets-test-for-convergence-of-improper-integrals), since $
x \mapsto \dfrac{\ln x}{x^2\sqrt{x^2-4}}$is monotonic decreasing to $0$ over $[3, \infty)$ and
$
\left|\int_3^b \sin x \:dx\right|<2.
$

Comment: How do I prove that sin is bounded by $2$? I need to evalute $\int_{3}^{\infty}sinx dx$?

Comment: @newhere you have $\left| -\int_{3}^b \sin x dx \right|=\left| [-\cos x]_3^b \right|\le 2$. The upper bound is not $\infty$, please see the link I gave in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For large enough $x$, the integrand behaves like $\dfrac{\sin x\log x}{x^3}$.

Show that the integral of the modulus of this quantity, converges. You are done.

Answer (score 1):

Actually , you do not need the Dirichlet test, because the integral is absolutely convergent: for $x\geq 3$,
$$0\leq\frac{|\sin x| \cdot \ln x}{x^2\sqrt{x^2-4}}\leq \frac{1\cdot x}{x^2\sqrt{x^2-4}}\sim\frac{1}{x^2}$$
and $\int_3^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{x^2}$ is convergent.

Comment: if the integral was just $\int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^2\sqrt{x^2-4}}$ could I say that it like $\frac{1}{x^2}$?

Comment: @newhere. You have better than that because $\frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{x^2-4}}\sim \frac{1}{x^3}$ as $x\to+\infty$.
Moreover, near $2^+$ we have  $\frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{x^2-4}}\sim \frac{1}{8\sqrt{x-2}}$. Hence your improper integral is convergent.

Answer (score 1):

For $x\geq3$, you have $\ln (x)/\sqrt {x^2-4}<1$, so
$$
\int_3^\infty\left|\frac {\sin x\ \ln x}{x^2\,\sqrt {x^2-4 }}\right|\,dx
= \int_3^\infty\frac {|\sin x|\ \ln x}{x^2\,\sqrt {x^2-4 }}\,dx
\leq\int_3^\infty\frac  {1}{x^2}\,dx <\infty
$$
and the integral converges absolutely.