# For what values of $\alpha\in{\mathbb{R}}$ is $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin{x^2}}{x^{\alpha}}dx$ convergent?

Tags: calculus

Rewriting I get

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{1}^{n}\frac{\sin{x^2}}{x^{\alpha}}dx.$$

Substituting $t=x^2,\quad dt=2xdx$ I get

$$\frac{1}{2}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{1}^{n}\frac{\sin{t}}{t\cdot x^{\alpha-1}}dt.$$

I don't really see where this leads me.

Comment: A formalist reader would ask what $x^{\alpha-1}$ is in your second integral.

Comment: Well, it's actually $$\frac{1}{2}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{1}^{n}\frac{\sin{t}}{x\cdot x^{\alpha}}dt.$$ Now I factor out an $x$ from $x^\alpha$ to get a $t$, but then I have to subtract $1$ from the exponent.

Comment: You are missing the point: either you *make* a substitution (and thus you substitute everything that needs to be substituted) or you *don't*. There is no in-between.

Comment: You suggest I replace $x^{\alpha-1}$ with $\sqrt{t}^{\alpha-1}?$ How will this help me?

Comment: I don't know, on top of my head. But at least you know what you are working with.

Comment: We can show that all $\alpha\geq 1$ works. Denoting $f(x)=\sin(x^2)$ and $g(x)=x^{-\alpha}$, note that $g(x)$ is bounded and monotonic on $[1,\infty)$ and $g(x)\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$. Also, note that $\int\limits_1^X f(x)\,\mathrm dx$ is bounded for all $X\geq 1$ (see [Fresnel integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral#Definition)), so by [Dirichlet's test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/141322/215900), we see that $\int\limits_1^\infty f(x)g(x)\,\mathrm dx$ converges for all $\alpha\geq 1$

Comment: @PrasunBiswas - This is single variable calculus, we are not yet introduced to Fresnel integral.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli $e^{(\alpha-1)\log(x)}$

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume $\alpha> -1$, then perform the substitution $x\mapsto\sqrt{z}$ and a step of integration by parts:
$$\int_{1}^{n}\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^\alpha}\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{n^2}\frac{\sin(z)}{z^{\frac{\alpha+1}{2}}}\,dz\stackrel{\text{IBP}}{=}\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1-\cos z}{z^{\frac{\alpha+1}{2}}}\right]_{1}^{n^2}+\frac{\alpha+1}{4}\int_{1}^{n^2}\frac{1-\cos z}{z^{\frac{\alpha+3}{2}}}\,dz$$
We get that $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\text{LHS}$ is finite iff $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{1}^{n^2}\frac{1-\cos z}{z^{\frac{\alpha+3}{2}}}\,dz$ is finite. $1-\cos z$ is a periodic non-negative function with mean value $1$, hence (by integration by parts again) the wanted limit is finite iff $\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{dz}{z^{\frac{\alpha+3}{2}}}$ is finite, and any value of $\alpha > -1$ does the job.

The cases $\alpha=-1$ and $\alpha <-1$ can be studied through the same approach.