# For what $a$ does this $\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)\cos(1/x)}{x^a}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence

> For what $a$ does this $\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)\cos(1/x)}{x^a}$ converge?

I’m preparing for a test and this exercise has me wondering:
I though about breaking it up to $(0,1)$ and $(1,+\infty)$ interval but I don’t know how to do the $(0,1)$ part, the $(1,+\infty)$ should be doable by Abel-Dirichlet criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. Consider two improper integrals:
$$\int_1^{+\infty}\sin(x)\cdot \frac{\cos(1/x)}{x^a}\,dx$$
and 
$$\int_0^1\frac{\sin(x)\cos(1/x)}{x^a}\,dx=\int_1^{+\infty}\cos(t)\cdot\frac{\sin(1/t)}{t^{2-a}}dt$$
where $t=1/x$.
Now use [Dirichlet's test for convergence of improper integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141048/dirichlets-test-for-convergence-of-improper-integrals)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I would like to know in the second integral why there is t^(2-a) in the deniminator?

Comment: After letting $t=1/x$ then $dx=-dt/t^2 $.

Comment: I literally always forget about that when substituting, thanks a lot! Have a nice day