# For which $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ this integral converges?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence

Consider we have $$\int_0^1 \frac{\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{(\sqrt{x} - x)^\alpha}dx$$

As I understand I have to use [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test), but is there all theorem's conditions are satisfied?

Maybe we have to make substitution $t = \frac{1}{x}$ and it helps? I got some troubles with this and maybe someone can help me.

Comment: Do you know when $$\int_0^1 x^{-\alpha/2}dx$$ converges?

Comment: Dirichlet's test is for *series*, not for improper integrals.

Comment: As I know it converges for $\alpha > 2$, right?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos as I know it also works for integrals with similar conditions. 
[Here's a post about it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141048/dirichlets-test-for-convergence-of-improper-integrals#:~:text=Dirichlet's%20test%20claims%20that%20for,afg%20is%20convergent.)

Comment: @José Carlos Santos there is a Dirichlet's test for improper integral, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test#Improper_integrals

Comment: @Someone Thank you. I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure $\alpha$ is any real number? Can you state the definition of Dirichlet's Test that you're using? The one I know is—

**Dirichlet's Test:** If $g(x)$ is a bounded monotonic function for $x≥a$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim\limits_{x \to ∞} g(x)=0$ and $f$ is a function such that $\displaystyle \left| \int_a^x f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t \right|$ is bounded for $x≥a$ then $\displaystyle \int_a^∞ f(x)g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ is convergent.

I think if you this test, it will not work for all real values of $\alpha$

Comment: Thank you. Test really works for all $\alpha > 0$. But  can we say something about other values of $\alpha$ maybe without a test using different ideas?

Comment: I suppose you can that the Dirichlet's test is inconclusive?

Comment: That's reason why I'm asking other ways to find $\alpha$