# If $f:[1,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}, 0\ge f\in C^{1} ,x<y\implies f(y)\le f(x) ,\lim_{x\to \infty} xf(x)=L$ then $\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x) \cos{x} < \infty $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convergence-divergence

---

#### Question

Let $f:[1,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ s.t:

- $f\in C^{1}$
- $f(x)\ge 0$
- $\forall x<y:f(y)\le f(x)$ , $x\ne y
  \in [1,\infty) $
- $\lim_{x\to \infty} xf(x)=L\in (0,\infty)$

Prove $\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x) \cos{x} \ dx < \infty $ and $\int_{1}^{\infty} \left| f(x) \cos{x} \right| \ dx $ diverges.

---

I want to show $\lim_{x\to \infty }f(x)=0$ because then I can prove $\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x) \cos{x} \ dx < \infty $ by Dirichlet's test for convergence of improper integral.
As for $\int_{1}^{\infty} \left| f(x) \cos{x} \right| \ dx $ I have not idea where to begin.
I would appreciate guidance/answer.

Thank you in advance!

---

#### EDIT

- I see now why $\lim_{x\to \infty }f(x)=0$.

Comment: Your conditions imply that  $0 \le f(x) < \frac{2L}{x}$ for sufficiently large $x$.

Comment: @MartinR You're right. Thanks!!

Comment: @MartinR I edited the post and added what else needed to be proven (I forgot to mention it in the first place).

Comment: For the second integral apply the fact that $\int\limits_1^\infty{|\cos x|\over x}\,dx$ is divergent.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc In order to use that you need to show $\frac{|\cos x|}{x} \le  \left| f(x) \cos{x} \right| $. How can I deduce that?

I thought using $\lim_{x\to \infty} xf(x)=L\in (0,\infty)$ and say $0<\frac{L}{2}<xf(x)$ for   sufficiently large $x$. Then multiply it by $|\cos{x}|$ and devide by $x$.

Comment: That's exactly what I had in mind: $f(x)|\cos x|\ge {L\over 2x}|\cos x|$ for large $x.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Cool. Thanks :)

Comment: You came up with the same idea :)

Comment: It follows from Dirichlet's test for convergence of improper integrals that  $\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x) \cos{x} \ dx < \infty $ -see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141048/dirichlets-test-for-convergence-of-improper-integrals

Comment: @BotnakovN. I know, I said it in the post.