# How to show that this improper integral converges

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

The integral in question is: $$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\sin^3(x)}{\sqrt{x}}dx$$
Graphically, I can see that the integral converges to about 0.5, but I've been unable to prove algebraically that the integral actually converges.

I've tried to do a comparison test, but I haven't been able to come up with a function that is larger and that I can show also converges.

How can I prove that this integral converges?

Comment: Hint: Estimate the integral between $2\pi n$ and $2\pi(n+1)$ for $n$ a positive integer.

Comment: I'm not sure if it notifies you when I edit my answer but I initially glossed over a somewhat important subtlety that has now been clarified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We first break the integral into portions on which the sign is constant,

$$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\sin^3(x)}{\sqrt{x}}dx= \int_1^{\pi}\frac{\sin^3(x)}{\sqrt{x}}dx + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\frac{\sin^3(x)}{\sqrt{x}}dx.$$

Now, the terms on the right hand sum are certainly alternating in sign and decreasing in absolute value, since for each $x$ we have

$$\frac{|\sin^3(x)|}{\sqrt{x}}\geq \frac{|\sin^3(x+\pi)|}{\sqrt{x+\pi}}.$$

Moreover, they are converging in absolute value to $0$, since $$\frac{|\sin^3(x)|}{\sqrt{x}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}},$$ and the latter's integral over $[n\pi,(n+1)\pi ]$ is at most $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{n}}$.
Therefore the integral converges by the alternating series test.

##### Remark

Strictly speaking, I was a little bit shady here, in that I implicitly suggested that if
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} f(x)\,dx$$ converges, then so does
$$\int_{\pi}^\infty f(x)\,dx.$$
This is not necessarily true for general $f$ (just let $f\equiv n$ on $[n\pi,(n+\frac{1}{2})\pi)$ and $f\equiv -n$ on $[(n+\frac{1}{2})\pi,(n+1)\pi)$), but it can be easily verified to hold when $f$ does not change sign within the interval $[n\pi,(n+1)\pi]$, as is the case in our scenario.  After all, in the case the sign does not change, we can trap the finite integrals
$$\int_{\pi}^\alpha f(x)\,dx.$$
between successive partial sums
$$\sum_{n=1}^M\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} f(x)\,dx.$$

Answer (score 1):

The answer is based on elementary trigonometric identities. We have $$\sin^3x={1\over 2}[1-\cos(2x)]\sin x\\ ={1\over 2}\sin x-{1\over 4}\sin( 3x) +{1\over 4}\sin x\\ ={3\over 4}\sin x-{1\over 4}\sin(3x)$$ The integrals $$\int\limits_1^\infty{1\over \sqrt{x}}\sin x \,dx\quad \int\limits_1^\infty{1\over \sqrt{x}}\sin (3x)\,dx$$ are convergent due to  [the Dirichlet test](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141048/dirichlets-test-for-convergence-of-improper-integrals).

**Remark**
The proof of the Dirichlet test in the particular cases above is pretty simple as it can be performed by integration by parts $$\int\limits_1^\infty{\sin x\over \sqrt{x}} \,dx=\cos 1-{1\over 2}\int\limits_1^\infty{\cos x\over x\sqrt{x}} \,dx $$

Answer (score 1):

*For your curiosity.*
$$I=\int\frac{\sin^3(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx=2 \int\sin ^3\left(t^2\right)\,dt=\frac 32\int \sin(t^2)\,dt-\frac 12\int \sin(3t^2)\,dt$$ So, you face [Fresnel sine integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral).
$$I=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{6}} \left(3 \sqrt{3}
   S\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} t\right)-S\left(\sqrt{\frac{6}{\pi
   }} t\right)\right)$$

$$J=\int_1^\infty\frac{\sin^3(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx=\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{6}} \left(-6 \sqrt{3}
   S\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}\right)+2 S\left(\sqrt{\frac{6}{\pi
   }}\right)-1+3 \sqrt{3}\right)$$ which is $0.551171$.

$$K=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^3(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx=\frac{1}{4} \left(3 \sqrt{3}-1\right) \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{6}}=0.759085$$

Answer (score 0):

For T a multiple of $2\pi$, $T>0$, let's bound how much mass is added to the integral between a new period from $T$ and $T+2\pi$.

$$\int_{T}^{T+2\pi}\frac{sin^3(x)}{\sqrt{x}}dx \leq \int_{T}^{T+\pi}\frac{\sin^3(x)}{\sqrt{T}}dx - \int_{T+\pi}^{T+2\pi}\frac{|\sin^3(x)|}{\sqrt{T+2\pi}}dx$$
=$$\frac{4\pi}{3}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{T}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{T+2\pi}}\right).$$

Now, telescoping series ...

Comment: I don't quite understand what the second and third integrals you wrote represent and where they came from. I assume that you solved the two integrals to arrive at the expression below, and I do understand that it'll be a telescoping series when summed (which is clearly finite).

Comment: Do you mean $|\sin^3 x|$ in the second integral?

Comment: I'm trying to argue that integral remainder (after $T$) is bounded above by this telescoping series.  The $4/3$ comes from integrating $\sin^3(x) dx$.